# RAILS V2.3 - (redmine) new unique field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am writing a little plugin for my company redmine to assign unique documents [progressive] codes

the code I wrote so far works, but I don't think it is multi threads proof as there is a chance two users get the same document code.

I would like to find a way to lock the table while getting the last number and creating the new record with the incremented document number (D9999)

This is the active record:

```
class Documenti < ActiveRecord::Base
unloadable

def self.nextest
   record=self.last
   if (record.nil?) then ultimo=sprintf("D0000")
   elsif (record.codice.nil?) then ultimo=sprintf("D0000") 
   else ultimo=record.codice
  end
if (/^D[0-9]{4}/ =~ ultimo) == 0 then
c=ultimo.split("D")
p=c[1].to_i + 1
t=sprintf("D%04i",p)
end

return t
 end
end
```

Controller then is like this:

```
def new
@documenti = Documenti.new
@documenti.codice=Documenti.nextest

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
end
end
```

so far the nextest value is not saved and another user can take the same value.

Comment: Doesn't `Documenti` already have an `id`? Why do you need to add another unique value?

Comment: company rules may change the documents naming convention such as D2013/001. In addition some record may be deleted creating a hole in ids. I wish the method nextest with the ability to control the algorithm for the new document code.

Comment: You can easily construct `'D2013/001'` from the `created_at` timestamp and the `id`. If you need to store this `id` then you could use a trigger to build it (or an `after_save` with a two `save` calls if you must stay in Rails-land). Gaps in `id` shouldn't be a problem, no sane database will fill the gaps; if you don't want gaps in your codes then you'd have to recode all of them after you delete a document and that's a bit silly (OTOH, business rules don't really have to make sense).

Comment: thnks for your proposal. I am going to implement the following flow:
Documenti.codice will be set as unique in the model.
nextest method will save the record and if an excenption will be thrown for duplicated record (i.e. another concurrent user took the same number meanwhile) the next attempted will be performed on D2013/002 003 and so forth...

Comment: I found a clue  [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)

Comment: But AR's uniqueness validation is subject to race conditions so you'll need a unique constraint inside the database and you'll have to trap the inevitable exceptions from that unique constraint. You'll also leave yourself open to gaps if two INSERTs start fighting each other.

Comment: I am fighting with trapping the exception infact. With no success so far.